# Sync different table structure in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, trigger, data-synchronization, unpivot

I have two table in different database host host. `activity_table` in **Host A** and `presence_table` in **Host B**. `presence_table` used by binary app where i don't have access to the source code but i have full access to the database. the `presence_table` table have this following structure

| column | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| finger_id | varchar |
| time_in | timestamp |
| time_out | timestamp |
| ... | ... |

**Example record**

| id | finger_id | time_in | time_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12a766d | 2022-08-01 12:32:01 | 2022-08-01 20:00:03 |

The `activity_table` is used by app which we are developing with this following structure

| column | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | integer |
| employee_id | integer |
| description | text |
| activity_time | datetime |
| created_at | timestamp |
| updated_at | timestamp |

**Example Record**

| id | employee_id | description | activity_time | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | Enter the office | 2022-08-01 12:32:01 | 2022-08-01 12:32:02 |  |
| 2 | 21 | Exit from office | 2022-08-01 20:00:03 | 2022-08-01 12:32:02 |  |

and of course i have `employee_finger_table` to pair employee with finger.

My question is how to automatically sync the `presence_table` to `activity_table` so when there is new record or updated record in `presence_table` synced to `activity_table` based on above example ? is there any tools or idea to address this problem ?

Comment: *is there any tools* No. *idea to address this problem* Create permanent federated table on host B linked to activity_table on host A, and update this linked table in the trigger. The problem - insert/update will fail if host A is not accessible. Another option - on host B save the data needed for remote table update into separate table and update table on host A as linked table from event procedure. One more option - replicate src table from host B to host A, on host A create a trigger which updates dest. table.

Comment: is there any way to insert record into foreign database table in MySQL ?

Comment: Yes. [The FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/).

Answer (score 0):

A DB "rule" is to "never have redundant information".  If your goal is to build *and maintain* that new table with redundant info, then consider building it on-the-fly when you need it, possibly as a "derived table" in a `FROM` clause.

It feels like the opposite of "pivot"; that is "un-pivot".  (I added that tag.)

This seems to encompass the main parts of the unpivot:

```
( SELECT e.eid, "Enter", a.time_in
      FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT e.eid, "Exit", a.time_out
      FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... )
```

If you will be inserting that into another table:

```
INSERT INTO activity_table
    SELECT e.eid, "Enter", a.time_in
        FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... 
    ;
INSERT INTO activity_table
    SELECT e.eid, "Exit", a.time_out
        FROM ... JOIN ... ON ...
    ;
```

Comment: thanks for your response **Rick James**. But i need the record is persisted in `activity_table`

Comment: I added the INSERTs.